# How to fix is not load JS from CDN at vách ngăn vệ sinh

Tags: amp-html

I really like AMP, so I designed this standard phone access interface.Everything is fine for over a year. A few days ago, my AMP was inaccessible from search results.

ex: press: "vách ngăn vệ sinh" , my site: https://vachnganvesinhgiare.com.
When click in search results, it's not load in mobile.

I have checked all websites that use AMP have the same error.

The reason is that the js file in cdn is not loaded or loaded but gives an error.Even on the homepage of the AMP is similar.

View in video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0G-kQ6yGSAA

[amp.dev is not load js in cdn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltrlp.png)

I have tried many phones and many browsers. But the situation is still the same.

Google no longer supports AMP, right?

Google no longer supports AMP, right?

Google no longer supports AMP, right?

Now how should I fix the error to keep running AMP?

Now how should I fix the error to keep running AMP?

[my website is not load js in cdn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBa4r.png)

Answer (score 0):

js is blocked in Vietnam by government's firewall, try in vpn or proxy, it's still working